# Set dataframe value based on condition of another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Table 1:

| ID | Name | Column C | Column D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1234hj | Bob | 1 | 1 |
| nkj234 | Joe | 2 | 2 |
| ji3251 | Schmoe | 3 | 3 |

Table 2:

| ID | Name |
| --- | --- |
|  | Bob |
|  | Joe |
|  | Sam |

I currently have 2 dataframes like so. How do i extract the ID from table 1 and set it as ID in table 2 IF the name matches?

I've tried this code but requires same labelling. (This may not even be correct)

```
df2['ID'] = np.where(df['Name'] == df2['Name'], 
                        df['Prompt'], df2['ID'])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
df2['ID'] = df2['Name'].map(df.set_index('Name')['ID'])
```

`pd.merge` is also an option here.

Answer (score 0):

```
table2 = pd.merge(table1[['ID','Name']], table2[['Name']], how='right', on='Name')
```